# Resize windows size according to title length.

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, resize, word-wrap

I have a window (WPF) which has a long title. When the size of window is increased dynamically, the title is shown properly. In one case size of window decreased dynamically. In that case full title is not shown. I want to resize the window according to title or textwrap the title, so that full title will be shown. Is there any solution for this?

```
<Window x:Class="Viewer.View.SelectorWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
    xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
    Icon="pack://application:,,,/Images/Viewer.png" WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner" ResizeMode="CanMinimize"
    Title="Registration and visualization from multiple data sets" Height="450" SizeToContent="Width"
    >
```

Comment: U can to use Javascript for any client magic

Comment: For resizing a WPF window see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7103169/resizing-wpf-window-programmatically-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @qwert_ukg Javascript?

Comment: @Ignatius u can determine current width by ```window``` or ```element``` ```width``` property, and rerender your text value as u wish. And also in another case u can control your ```window``` size (i mean DOM element) by text wrapper size

Comment: @Ignatius Oh wtf, sorry, WPF. No JS, forget it

Comment: @JeroenHeier Thanks.I will give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that this approach will lead to great success without a lot of effort. Consider the following problems:

- Do you really want to fit your window size depending on the title length? If the title is really really long, you are creating a really really big window just because of the title.
- It's not that intuitive to put much information into window title
- If it's possible to realize at all, you probably have to dig deeper than simply setting some WPF properties.

My solution would be to simply display the title in your view. A simple TextBlock that binds to the window title. So you are much more flexible.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Yes it is not feasible to put much information in window title. But binding TextBlock to window title won't solve the problem.

Comment: I guess your problem is not to set a specific the window size. It's more about displaying information. Why is it not a solution for you to show this information in another way?

Comment: Because there are lot of windows (which has titles) in my application and I want to make all visual elements consistent throughout my application.